# Keras categorical_entropy outputs shape unknown?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

```
In [43]: x = keras.Input(shape=(10,))

In [44]: keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(x, x, from_logits=True)
Out[44]: <tf.Tensor 'softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_11/Reshape_2:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>
```

Pretty much says it all. End up shape the usual TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() with this.

Comment: In Keras (not tf.Keras) it would display the shape as `(?,)` due to the simple fact the batch size is not specified. For example, you can try `batch_shape=(20,10)` in the input layer, and probably you would get `shape=(20,)` in the displayed output.

Comment: Iirc regular keras is not compatible with tensorflow 2.0

Comment: Ah, yeah I should call this tf.keras I guess. So that is the one that ships with tf 2.0.